# Pyautocad Object/Text Layer change

Tags: python

So I am creating text that I want to add to the document and the Layer the text appears on is the currently active layer.  I want to be able to assign this text to a different layer so that I can later turn that layer on, based on specific conditions.

I found some documentation regarding changing the layer of an object and it said to use the Method.Layer and then = "Layer" (as long as that layer is defined, which it is in my code)

This is not working however, this code is just a sample from a larger file I have, here it is:

```
import pyautocad
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint

acad = pyautocad.Autocad(16)
print(acad.doc.name)

LayerText = acad.doc.Layers.Item("Layer4")

T = acad.model.AddText("LARGE TEXT", APoint (0, 0), 100)
T.Layer = "LayerText"

print (T.Layer)

LayerText.LayerOn = True
```

it is giving me an error at T.layer = "LayerText" I am assuming the .Layer method is incorrect for what I am trying to achieve but the document I found says otherwise

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the string with the name of the layer instead of the variable you created to identify it.
You can also avoid to write the line in which you define "LayerText" and directly replace it with the function that creates the layer.

Here it is the example with your case, let me know if it works.

```
acad.doc.Layers.Add("Layer4")
T=acad.model.AddText("LARGE TEXT", APoint(0, 0), 100)
T.Layer="Layer4"
```